# App.Config not working for sub directories

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following configuration file and 2 assembly places that i want my app to look into.. However it doesn't seem to work with the subdirectory `lib/awesomium`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
      <probing privatePath="lib/awesomium" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please show some code so we know how you're trying to do this.

Comment: [MSDN: Assembly Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) have you checked out the documentation and or done a google search ||
[Probing Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @roryap what code to show lol i have some dlls that i put into a custom folder and i want the application to detect them...

Comment: @DJKRAZE yea i am done with both and can't get it working

Comment: @roryap and does'nt the whole app.config count as 'some code' ?

Comment: look at the example in the second link looks like your paths are incorrect.. if not then try to set this in code behind using `Server.MapPath`

Comment: @DJKRAZE you made my day... thank you very much... your 2nd link works it was a mistake in how i write the paths. You can post this as an answer

Comment: not a problem glad I could make your day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your path ie. `/` are incorrect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib;lib\awesomium;" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

taken from this example [MSDN: Probing Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```